# Tkinter gui Creation

Tags: python, tkinter

**main.py**

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import *


import main_support


def popup1(event, *args, **kwargs):
        Popupmenu1 = tk.Menu(main_support.root, tearoff=0)
        Popupmenu1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        Popupmenu1.configure(activeborderwidth="1")
        Popupmenu1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        Popupmenu1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        Popupmenu1.configure(borderwidth="1")
        Popupmenu1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        Popupmenu1.configure(font="-family {Segoe UI} -size 9")
        Popupmenu1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        Popupmenu1.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)


class Header:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.methodSelectionValue = []
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=[('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        top.geometry("600x450+664+264")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(1924, 1061)
        top.resizable(1,  1)
        top.title("Toplevel 0")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#f0f0f0f0f0f0")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.top = top
        self.combobox = tk.StringVar()

        self.Label1 = tk.Label(self.top)
        self.Label1.place(relx=-0.033, rely=0.0, height=41, width=634)
        self.Label1.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label1.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label1.configure(background="#b90746")
        self.Label1.configure(compound='center')
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(font="-family {Calisto MT} -size 16 -weight bold -slant italic")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''Calculator''')

        self.TFrame1 = ttk.Frame(self.top)
        self.TFrame1.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.12, relheight=0.856, relwidth=0.958)

        self.TFrame1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.TFrame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.TFrame1.configure(relief="groove")

        self.Labelframe1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.TFrame1)
        self.Labelframe1.place(relx=0.47, rely=0.026, relheight=0.948, relwidth=0.504)
        self.Labelframe1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.Labelframe1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(text='''Main Window''')
        self.Labelframe1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.Label2 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label2.place(relx=0.038, rely=0.11, height=31, width=90, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label2.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label2.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label2.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label2.configure(text='''Class Selection''')

        self.TCombobox1 = ttk.Combobox(self.Labelframe1, values=['Basic', 'Advance'])
        self.TCombobox1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.setMethodValue)
        self.TCombobox1.place(relx=0.421, rely=0.121, relheight=0.058, relwidth=0.531, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TCombobox1.configure(textvariable=self.combobox)
        self.TCombobox1.configure(takefocus="")

        self.Label3 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label3.place(relx=0.038, rely=0.274, height=21, width=111, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label3.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label3.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label3.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label3.configure(text='''Method Selection''')

        self.TCombobox2 = ttk.Combobox(self.Labelframe1, values=self.methodSelectionValue)
        self.TCombobox2.place(relx=0.414, rely=0.274, relheight=0.058, relwidth=0.528, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TCombobox2.configure(takefocus="")

        self.TEntry1 = ttk.Entry(self.Labelframe1)
        self.TEntry1.place(relx=0.138, rely=0.493, relheight=0.112, relwidth=0.262, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TEntry1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TEntry1.configure(cursor="ibeam")

        self.Label4 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label4.place(relx=0.207, rely=0.411, height=21, width=74, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label4.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label4.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label4.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label4.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label4.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label4.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label4.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label4.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label4.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label4.configure(text='''Input 1''')

        self.TEntry2 = ttk.Entry(self.Labelframe1)
        self.TEntry2.place(relx=0.621, rely=0.493, relheight=0.112, relwidth=0.262, bordermode='ignore')
        self.TEntry2.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TEntry2.configure(cursor="ibeam")

        self.Label5 = tk.Label(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Label5.place(relx=0.655, rely=0.411, height=21, width=44, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Label5.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label5.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label5.configure(anchor='w')
        self.Label5.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label5.configure(compound='left')
        self.Label5.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label5.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label5.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label5.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label5.configure(text='''Input 2''')

        self.Button1 = tk.Button(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.397, rely=0.685, height=34, width=57, bordermode='ignore')
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(compound='left')
        self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''Run''')

        self.TFrame2 = ttk.Frame(self.TFrame1)
        self.TFrame2.place(relx=0.017, rely=0.026, relheight=0.948, relwidth=0.426)
        self.TFrame2.configure(relief='groove')
        self.TFrame2.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.TFrame2.configure(relief="groove")
        self.background = tk.PhotoImage(file="path/of/your/image.png")
        tk.Label(self.TFrame2, image=self.background).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')

    def setMethodValue(self, event):
        selectedValue = self.TCombobox1.get()
        if selectedValue == "Basic":
            self.TCombobox2["values"] = ["Add", "Sub"]
        elif selectedValue == "Advance":
            self.TCombobox2["values"] = ["Multiply", "Division", "Modulus"]
        self.TCombobox2.current()


def start_up():
    main_support.mains()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_support.mains()
```

**main_support.py**

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

import main


def mains(*args):
    '''Main entry point for the application.'''
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' , root.destroy)
    # Creates a toplevel widget.
    global _top1, _w1
    _top1 = root
    _w1 = main.Header(_top1)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.start_up()
```

**backend.py**

```
class Basic:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    def sub(self):
        return self.a - self.b


class Advance:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def multiply(self):
        return self.a * self.b

    def division(self):
        return self.a / self.b

    def modulus(self):
        return self.a % self.b


a = int(input("Enter first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter second number: "))
obj = Basic(a, b)
print("Add Result: ", obj.add())
print("Sub Result: ", obj.sub())
obj2 = Advance(a, b)
print("Multiply Result: ", obj2.multiply())
print("Division Result: ", obj2.division())
print("Modulus Result: ", obj2.modulus())
```

Currently stuck at the backend implementation where after selecting required class and method for that particular class and then enter two input values in GUI and after click on run button, I need a box where it will display this output, just below run button.

secondly, consider input as follow:

```
class selection: Basic
Method selection: Add
input1: 10
input2: 20
```

After click run button in GUI, this should go to `backend.py` file and find `Basic` class and inside it `Add` method and run this. How to add this link for all classes and methods respectively. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Use a dictionary with class and function name as keys and function reference as the values.  Also don't import module like `import tkinter as tk` and then `from tkinter import *`.  Using first one is recommended.

Comment: Can you show on how to do it

Comment: Please try to reduce the code example to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that isn't necessary in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not able to get it still. can anyone help me,